# Getting data from xml with specific data name and value key

Tags: c#, xml

I want to get data from xml but there are lots of tags, fields and value keys. I couldn't select the value which I want. How can I select the "Error" value from this XML with C#?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Database xmlns="http://www.example.com/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Datas>
  <Data name="sMsg" access="private" xsi:type="collection" type="string">
     <Value key="Cycle" value="deger1" />
     <Value key="Error" value="deger2" />
     <Value key="Info" value="deger3" />
     <Value key="Jog" />
     <Value key="Warning" />
  </Data>
  <Data name="tTabla" access="private" xsi:type="array" type="tabla" size="1">
     <Field name="dddd" xsi:type="array" type="bool" size="1" />
     <Field name="ssss" xsi:type="array" type="bool" size="1" />
     <Field name="aaaa" xsi:type="array" type="num" size="1" />
     <Field name="rrrr" xsi:type="collection" type="num">
         <Value key="Actuel" />
        <Value key="Expected" />
     </Field>
  </Data>
 </Datas>
</Database>
```

Comment: I'd use LINQ to XML. There are *lots* of questions around extracting data from XML here on Stack Overflow. I suggest you do some research, have a go yourself, and then if you're still having problems, edit the question with your code so far and what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace d = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var result = (string)
    doc.Descendants(d + "Data")
       .Elements(d + "Value")
       .FirstOrDefault(o => (string) o.Attribute("key") == "Error")
       .Attribute("value");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: How can we get all the values under the <Data name="sMsg">?

Comment: That's a different question. But, you can easily modify this answer to do that if you're familiar with LINQ.. What do you think? Give it a try, and post another question if you can't get your idea to work

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple "Error" values for your attributes, you can do:

```
IEnumerable<XAttribute> answer = xml.Descendants().Attributes().Where(node => node.Value == "Error");
foreach (var xAttribute in answer)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xAttribute.Value);
}
```

If you only want the first or there is only one:

```
string answer = xml.Descendants().Attributes().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Value == "Error");
```

Note `FirstOrDefault` may yield `null` if it doesn't find any "Error" values inside your xml.

These queries are done using [LINQ To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), i strongly encourage you to read up.

Comment: XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(sXmlResponseFromRobot);   I use this codes but xmlDoc.Descendants gives error. I have already addes using System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` are different classes.

Comment: I see. But when I create a new xdocument and try to add xdocument.load or xdocument.parse it gives error. Should I add a library or reference? There is no problem with xdocument, only It's functions don't work

Comment: Ok I got it I will try and let you know

Comment: Ok print the var answer with <MessageBox.Show(answer.ToString());> and the result is <key="Error"> but I want to see value of this so "deger1"

Comment: Did you use the `FirstOrDefault` or the one with `Where`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it returns the `XElement` with `Key` equal to `Error`

```
 XDocument m = XDocument.Load(@"Path");
 var res = m.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("Value") && x.Attribute("key") != null && x.Attribute("key").Value.Equals("Error")).FirstOrDefault();
```